# Create a Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2019 from web page in C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I Have a web pages in .NET 6 MVC.

Is possible through C# create a Task scheduler? (Hosting are Windows Server 2019)

Thank You.

Comment: "Is it possible"?  Yes.  Likely involving more tools than just a web page.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I Tested this package but without success, i think not run in a web page:
https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler

Comment: The duplicate links to the COM interfaces that can be used for this, and there's the problem - most Windows APIs are COM which can't be used easily from .NET Core. At the very least the web app must target Win32 explicitly so it can use COM. Even Powershell Core doesn't have any scheduling commands

Comment: `but without success` what does that mean? If it's a permission error, you can solve it by using an account with the correct permissions. An IIS APPPOOL account certainly doesn't have the correct permissions out of the box